# Invalid conversion from throwing function of type (_,_,_) throws -> Void to non-throwing function type (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void

Tags: ios, swift, try-catch, urlsession, json-serialization

I have written this code:

```
func getjson() {
        let urlPath = "https://api.whitehouse.gov/v1/petitions.json?limit=100"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Task completed")
            if(error != nil) {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            let err: NSError?
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                if(err != nil) {
                    print("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
                }
                if let results: NSArray = jsonResult["results"] as? NSArray {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.tableData = results
                        self.Indextableview.reloadData()
                    })
                }
            }
        })

        task.resume()

    }
```

And after update to XCode 7 it gives me this error: Invalid conversion from throwing function of type (_, _, _) throws -> Void to non-throwing function type (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void. It is in line, where is let task.

Thanks

Comment: Point out the line causing the issue and update your question with the complete and exact error message.

Comment: But where should I use try? @LeoDabus

Comment: Do try after try add code that should run if successful

Comment: I have updated complete error message @rmaddy

Comment: try code been use in a not try-catch block.it's happen to me.fix it by change `try xxx` to `try? xxx`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to implement Do Try Catch error handling as follow:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

extension URL {
    func asyncDownload(completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ response: URLResponse?, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared
            .dataTask(with: self, completionHandler: completion)
            .resume()
    }
}
```

---

```
let jsonURL = URL(string: "https://api.whitehouse.gov/v1/petitions.json?limit=100")!
let start = Date()
jsonURL.asyncDownload { data, response, error in

    print("Download ended:", Date().description(with: .current))
    print("Elapsed Time:", Date().timeIntervalSince(start), terminator: " seconds\n")
    print("Data size:", data?.count ?? "nil", terminator: " bytes\n\n")

    guard let data = data else {
        print("URLSession dataTask error:", error ?? "nil")
        return
    }

    do {
        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
        if let dictionary = jsonObject as? [String: Any],
            let results = dictionary["results"] as? [[String: Any]] {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                results.forEach { print($0["body"] ?? "", terminator: "\n\n") }
      //        self.tableData = results
      //        self.Indextableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("JSONSerialization error:", error)
    }
}
print("\nDownload started:", start.description(with: .current))
```

Comment: Is there a way to hand the Error further up the chain? Because my "getjson" function is in a separate class. And i don't want to print the error description but show it in an UIAlertController to the user. But the UIAlertController can only be show from a UIViewController with calls the "getjson" function.

Comment: @Adarkas2302 being an asynchronous method, the easiest way to accomplish this would be posting a notification and adding an observer to the view controller you need to display the alert. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30541063/2303865

Comment: @HariHonor There is no switch on my code

Answer (score 21):

As Leo suggested, your problem is that you're using `try`, but not within the `do`-`try`-`catch` construct, which means that it infers that the closure is defined to throwing the error, but since it is not defined as such, you get that error.

So, add `do`-`try`-`catch`:

```
func getjson() {
    let urlPath = "https://api.whitehouse.gov/v1/petitions.json?limit=100"
    let url = URL(string: urlPath)!
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        print("Task completed")

        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        do {
            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] {
                if let results = jsonResult["results"] as? [Any] {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableData = results
                        self.indexTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let parseError {
            print("JSON Error \(parseError.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 2, replace all `NSError` with `ErrorType`

Try this.

```
  class func fetchWeatherForLocation(locationCode: String = "", shouldShowHUD: Bool = false, completionHandler: (data: NSDictionary?, error: ErrorType?) -> ()) {



    let url = NSURL(string: "myurl")               
    let task =  NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in

        if let dataWithKey = data {

            do {
                let jsonForDataWithTemprature = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataWithKey, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

                guard let arrayForDataWithKey :NSArray = jsonForDataWithTemprature as? NSArray else {
                    print("Not a Dictionary")
                    return
                }

                let dictionaryWithTemprature = arrayForDataWithKey.firstObject as! NSDictionary

                completionHandler(data: dictionaryWithTemprature, error: nil)

            }
            catch let JSONError as ErrorType {
                print("\(JSONError)")
            }

        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the error type in the code try-catch worked for me.

"replace all NSError with ErrorType"