# How can I call a function that creates a button from another viewcontroller?

Tags: swift

I have a function in my TuesdayViewController.swift that creates a button.

Whenever it's Tuesday, I want that button to appear in my ViewController.swift

I have this function in my TuesdayViewController:

```
func tuesdayView(){
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 200, width: 343, height: 45))
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    button.setTitle("Test button", for: .normal)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

}
```

If I call this function in Tuesday's viewDidLoad(), the button shows in the TuesdayViewController.

How can I make it so I call this function through my main ViewController and for the button to show in the main ViewController screen?

I have tried this in my main ViewController but the button doesn't appear:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){

super.viewDidLoad()
TuesdayViewController().tuesdayVew()


}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you just want to add the same kind of button from your `TuesdayViewController` into your `MainViewController`, and not adding the button to the `TuesdayViewController` by calling it in the `MainViewController`.

To do that, you just can declare your `tuesdayView` as a public property of your `TuesdayViewController`, like so:

**TuesdayViewController.swift**

```
class TuesdayViewController: UIViewController {
    public lazy var tuesdayView: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 200, width: 343, height: 45))
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.setTitle("Test button", for: .normal)
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(self.tuesdayView)
    }
}
```

And call that property like what you've been doing before.

**MainViewController.swift**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let button = TuesdayViewController().tuesdayView
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an observer with `NotificationCenter`:

First you need to create a Notification Name

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let notName = Notification.Name("notName")
}
```

TuesdayViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(tuesdayViewObserver), name: .notName, object: nil)

}

@objc func tuesdayViewObserver(_ notification: Notification) {
    //Here you call the tuesdayView function
    tuesdayView()
}
```

And in the controller in which you want to fire the method, you post the notification and the method will be executed:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .notName, object: nil)
}
```

For further info, I recommend you to take a look to [NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter) and how it works. [LINK](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/)

Comment: `@objc func tuesdayViewObserver(_ notification: Notification)` you should drop the NS prefix and if coding in Swift 4 you need to add @objc in front of your method. Also in your selector (notification:) it is not needed it can be inferred by the compiler `#selector(tuesdayViewObserver)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/30541063/2303865